# web.config defaultRedirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem to redirect to my error page.
In global.asax I have implemented Application_Error, so I can catch and log errors.

If I put this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errore.html" />
```

everything works...

with this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errore.aspx" />
```

it is show the page:
http://localhost:3821/Errore.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/pagine/Ricerca.aspx

BUT on Errore.aspx  Page_load() or OnError() are not called, and the page showed is just the standar one, (runtime error) that suggest to change to off the mode in customErrors.

This is on my pc, so there is not IIS... ...and I don't use authentication (not yet)

Any clue?

Thanks,
Alberto

UPDATE:
The error occur in Global.aspx, in Application_Start() . When the error occur, redirecting to an .aspx page will cause an error because the app is not up. The solution is to redirec to an html page.
Thanks to everyone
Alberto

Comment: Your default redirect page isn't guaranteed to load - for example, if ASP.NET can't compile your application.

Comment: I agree.I can add also if the "errore" page contains just HTML why don't you go for an .html insead of .aspx ?

Comment: If you type this down yourself in the address bar - http://localhost:3821/Errore.aspx - Is your error page displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an unhandled exception somewhere in your errore.aspx file. Make sure you are using proper error handling there as well.

Comment: Throwing an exception without executing the Page_Load function?